# Issues with basic commands in gitbash

Tags: windows, git, bash, git-bash

I'm just getting started trying to use command line and gitbash, and I've run into some basic issues.

As I understand it from the lesson I'm trying to go through online, I can run gitbash on windows instead of standard command line I would find on Mac and Linux(?)

The blurb about it was:

*"WINDOWS USERS: You might want to jump ahead to the Installations Assignment and use the "Git Bash" application you'll install there instead of using the default Command Prompt. That way you can be sure all the commands will be the same."*

So I downloaded Gitbash via Railsinstaller but the first command, man/man ls, [gives me this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2Eax.png).

Am I misunderstanding the function of Gitbash? Do I need to install something to add on or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, one of the notable faults of Git Bash is that it does not ship with a `man` command, so no, you are not misunderstanding anything. If you try to `ls` or `cd` or `grep` you'll see that it works fine.

Without going into too much background, Git Bash is a shell environment on Windows that emulates standard POSIX terminal behavior and makes *some* common Linux tools available. I'm not personally prone to the reasoning behind this decision, but I just double-checked and `man` (and `man-db`, etc.) *are* available in the ecosystem behind the tool that Git Bash derives from. If you want to fight for it, you might want to open an issue on the Git for Windows GH repository; Johannes Schindelin is the lead maintainer there and is very active.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand Git Bash a bit better now. Would you recommend just going through these lessons with Linux instead?

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with Linux-esque systems, yes, because you'll have full-fledged Unix/POSIX functionality. If you are (which seems unlikely, since you're asking this), I would recommend looking into MSYS2 or Cygwin.